# How to retrieve data from a list of children that I don't know the name of in advance?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am very new to Firebase and Java and I am looking for a hopefully easy answer. This is my database:

[image]

In my code the user inputs a name and number from separate text fields. I use the name to generate a child in "Client." What I want to do is take the "Name" and "Number" values and output them into text on my application. Problem is I am having a hard time figuring out how to reference the children of Client to output the data. Alex, David, Will are just placeholders for really any value the user inputs so how do I reference a child I don't know the name of?

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve your Client datasnapshot

```
//Get datasnapshot at your "users" root node
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Client");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Get map of users in datasnapshot
                    collectInfo((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });
```

Then loop through clients, accessing their map

```
private void collectInfo(Map<String,Object> clients) {

    //iterate through each client
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : clients.entrySet()){

        //Get client map
        Map singleClient = (Map) entry.getValue();
        // Do whatever you want to do with single clients
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
DatabaseReference clientsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Client");
clientsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot clientSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(clientSnapshot.getKey()); // "Alex", "David", "Will"
            System.out.println(clientSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class)); // "Alex", "David", "Will"
            System.out.println(clientSnapshot.child("Number").getValue(String.class)); // "12345", "98765", "12345"
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

If you are just getting started with Android development and Firebase, I recommend taking [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) first. It will save you much time (and questions) going forward.

Comment: And yes, OP can take your FriendlyChat course also, because that's amazing!